# Ubuntu 14.04: Boot Repair is not working (No Boot Menu)

Tags: 14.04, dual-boot, boot-repair, boot-partition

I installed Windows 8 first and then Ubuntu 14.04. After installing Ubuntu 14.04, there was no boot menu, so I booted a live USB and used recommended repairs on boot-repair but there is still no boot menu.

I have two drives, one is 200 GB which has Windows installed and other is 1 TB which has Ubuntu installed. Could the reason be that they are installed on different partitions? Below is the URL which was generated at the end of the boot-repair:

http://paste.ubuntu.com/17697091

Hope someone can help. Thanks!

Comment: Have you gone into BIOS and set to boot from sdb drive or the 1TB drive? And you should remove wubi from Windows, that is not supported anymore. Also turn off Windows 8's fast start or always on hibernation. http://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=2324331&p=13488472#post13488472 You will not be able to boot Windows from grub menu with fast start on, nor be able to see any NTFS partition. Boot Windows drive directly with one time boot key Escape, f9 on HP, f10 or f12 on most others. Do not install grub to any partition, just to drive sdb. And keep Windows boot loader in sda.

Comment: @oldfred Fast start is turned off but I just realized that 1TB hard drive is present in the list of hard disk drives in BIOS settings but it is not visible in BOOT device priority list. Could this be the reason?

Comment: @oldfred I found the problem, I had to plug the 1 TB drive on the SATA1 port and other on SATA2 port since my motherboard could only boot from the SATA1 port and now it's working fine. Thanks for your comment. It gave me the insight. You can give a proper answer so that I can accept it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Have you gone into BIOS and set to boot from sdb drive or the 1TB drive?
It is unusual for a newer system to only boot from first drive. Some much older BIOS, only boot from larger drives if system in first 137GB of drive.
But make sure BIOS is set to AHCI, not IDE as that is the compatibility with the very old BIOS.

Also turn off Windows 8's fast start or always on hibernation. You will not be able to boot Windows from grub menu with fast start on, nor be able to see any NTFS partition.

http://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=2324331&p=13488472#post13488472

Boot Windows drive directly with one time boot key Escape, f9 on HP, f10 or f12 on most others.

Do not install grub to any partition, just to drive sdb. And keep Windows boot loader in sda, so you can directly boot it if Windows updates turns on fast startup again. Best to have Windows repair flash drive.

And you should remove wubi from Windows, that is not supported anymore.

https://wiki.ubuntu.com/WubiGuide
https://help.ubuntu.com/community/Wubi